# Elasticsearch store brands and products, one to many relationship, search and paginate on both entities

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have products and their brands,
Earlier my mapping was

```
{
"product_id",
"product_name",
"brand_id",
"brand_name",
"city_id",
//other filters associated with product
}
```

it was working fine until i needed to search on brands too, with the current mapping it was hard to paginate the document
so i created a separate mapping for brands, now the schema was

```
{
"product_id",
"product_name",
"brand_id",
"city_id",
"doc_type"   //product
//other filters associated with product
}
{
"brand_id",
"brand_name",
"doc_type"   //brand
}
```

But i cannot search for a brand with filter associated to product, for ex find brand with products in city A, i can use application level joins but suppose if i got 100k products with current filter i need to store those ids in memory before i query on brand table. i can add those filters in brand table but it is not only wrong, it will be very hard to keep track of updates and deletion of products in brand. being a newbie in nosql my design seems absolutely wrong.

how can i design it better so to enable search on both products and brands with filters associated to products?

Comment: Do the opposite of relational databases, instead of normalising and keeping data in different documents/index and then thinking in terms of join, de-normalise and keep all info in one document.

Comment: In the first schema thats what i did, but fetching brands needed distinct aggregation and pagination wasnt possible

Comment: In such a case I would suggest to have a separate index for brand which you can use when searching only on brand, along with the de-normalised product schema.

Comment: Another approach could be making use of [join data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/parent-join.html) and [parent join queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/parent-join.html#_parent_join_queries_and_aggregations). Here brand can be parent and products will be child.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nishant, i can use joins but i have heard they tax performance and we should use them when absolutely necessary, i was hoping if i could redesign my model so it also be efficient